# How to use a target list to match a row in a dataframe in R, and once matched, add a value to a new column

Tags: r, match, data-manipulation, target

I have a *dataframe (A)* that contains a few columns of values and texts. *Column 1* contains names that **are not unique**. I have a list containing some of the same names that are present in dataframe A column 1, and they are unique. I want to **mach my list to the dataframe A**, and if values are matched, **create a new column 4 in dataframe A and add an "X"** to that row. Here is an example (duplicated value in Bold):

**Dataframe A:**

1           2       3
**Barb048  53458   0.004**
An590    345345 0.485
84Bur    53455  0.8474
hfgjeff  345    0.765
**Barb048   542    0.66**
Ann9457  4555   0.00746
uryhZe9  84     0.27777
(...)

**List:**

Barb048, hfgjeff, Ann9457 (...)

**Desired dataframe:**

1            2       3       4
**Barb048  53458   0.004    X**
An590    345345. 0.485
84Bur    53455  0.8474
hfgjeff  345    0.765       X
**Barb048   542    0.66     X**
Ann9457  4555   0.00746  X
uryhZe9  84     0.27777
(...)

I thought about creating a dataframe (B) with the values in the list, then including a column with X's in all its rows, then match dataframes, but I think using a *target list* would be much easier.

Comment: Please, before posting check the guidelines on how to ask a question and try to give a reproducible example so it is easier to answer.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `ifelse`and `%in%`:

```
df$new <- ifelse(df$X1 %in% names, "X", "")
```

Result:

```
df 
       X1 new
1 Barb048   X
2   An590  
3   84Bur  
4   hfgje  
5 Barb048   X
6 Ann9457   X
7 uryhZe9
```

Data:

```
# list of names:
names <- c("Barb048", "hfgjeff", "Ann9457")
# dataframe:
df <- data.frame(
  "X1" = c("Barb048","An590", "84Bur","hfgje","Barb048", "Ann9457", "uryhZe9")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution based on the one given by Chris Ruehlemann.

I loaded both datasets (dataframe and list) as dataframes (they were both in csv format). The columns I want to match are in column 1 of both datasets (and the columns are named C1).

Then I ran this code:

```
dfA <- read.csv2('DFA.csv', header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

dftarget <- read.csv2('targetlist.csv', header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)

dfA$new_column <- ifelse(dfA$C1 %in% dftarget$C1, "X", "")
```